# Is this mathematically valid?

Tags: generating-functions

Suppose, I have a generating function:
 *G(z) = Σ t<sub>n</sub>z<sup>n</sup>* 
 and an equation as:
*t<sub>n</sub>=t<sub>n-1</sub>+(n-1)*
I rewrite it in terms of *G(z)* as: 
*Σ t<sub>n</sub>z<sup>n</sup> = Σ t<sub>n-1</sub> z<sup>n</sup> + Σ n . z<sup>n</sup> - Σ z<sup>n</sup>*

*Σ t<sub>n</sub>z<sup>n</sup> = z Σ t<sub>n</sub> z<sup>n</sup> + Σ n . z<sup>n</sup> - Σ z<sup>n</sup>*

*G(z) = z G(z) + $\frac{n}{(1-z)}- \frac{1}{(1-z)}$*

Is the last step valid?

Thanks.

Comment: There should be a $t_{0}$ somewhere. When you take out the $z$ to get $z*G(z)$, you also need to take out the first term in the sequence.

Comment: "Is the last step valid?" No, because n should not appear in the evaluation of the series on the RHS. Once you correct this (and some problems of initialization mentioned in another comment), you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tackled this question in the following manner.

Given $G(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_nz^n$

and the equation $t_n=t_{n-1}+(n-1)$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_{n-1}z^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-1)z^n$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_nz^n=z\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_{n}z^n+{z^2\over(1-z)^2}$

$G(z)=zG(z)+{z^2\over(1-z)^2}$

$G(z)-zG(z)={z^2\over(1-z)^2}$

$G(z)(1-z)={z^2\over(1-z)^2}$

$G(z)={z^2\over(1-z)^3}$

$G(z)=z^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty {n(n-1)\over2}z^{n}$

$\therefore t_n={n(n-1)\over2}$

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can say

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t_{n} z^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t_{n-1} z^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1) z^n. $$

Thus,

$$ = t_{0}z + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t_{n} z^{n+1} +  z^{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1) z^{n-2}. $$

From here you can say

$$ G(z) = t_{0}z + zG(z) + z^{2}\frac{d}{dz} \Big( \frac{1}{1-z} \Big) $$

and solve for $G(z)$.

Comment: Uh, I have to prove this as $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, this seems to be a bit complicated.

Comment: You should get something like $G(z) = \frac{z^{2}}{(1-z)^3} = z^{2}\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}\Big(\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-z}\Big)$ and then write $\frac{1}{1-z}$ as a sum again. Then differentiate (twice) term by term. Make sure you justify why you can (if you need to).